# Windows Live Writer Webpreview and Weblayout

Tags: windows-live-writer

I'm working on implementing a blogging engine and want to make it compatible with windows live writer. I found an [excellent post](http://www.labs.jobserve.com/Articles.aspx/Building-Labs--XML-RPC-Backend-for-Windows-Live-Writer-in-C-with-WCF) on this, but what I can't find is documentation on the placeholder tags used in the weblayout and webpreview templates. The only page I can find referring to this files on MSDN is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463261.aspx) that doesn't mention the placeholder tags.

Anybody point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Tony

Answer (score 1):

The placeholders are:

```
{post-title}
{post-body}
```

[The msdn article that you linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463261.aspx) does state that, though.